# gulp-sass не компилирует scss-файлы в единый css

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, gulp, gulp-sass

Собираю проект галпом. Проблема с таской на сборку scss-файлов - плагин просто меняет разрешение `scss` на `css`, файлы не компилируются. Пути прописаны верно, ошибок в процессе сборки нет. В чем может быть причина?

```
/* Сама таска */
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(prefixer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/style'))
    .pipe(reload({
        stream: true
  }));
});

/* вотчер */
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch("src/sass/**/*.scss", ['sass']);
});
```

Вот что получается:
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_8kb.1532001775.png

P.S. показал только ту часть сборки, что относится к сборке стилей.

Comment: Ваш таск отрабатывает правильно. Вы сказали, что нужно скомпилировать все scss, он это и сделал. У вас нигде не прописана упаковка в один файл. Можете просто создать нечто вроде style.scss и в нем с помощью @import подключить ваши файлы. И компиляцию выполнять только для него

Comment: функцию предлагаемого вами `style.scss` у меня выполняет `main.scss` - туда выводятся все подключаемые файлы. Проблема в том, на выходе файл должен быть действительно один, т.к. пилю amp-версию сайта и плагин, проверяющий "тяжесть" стилей (`gulp-amp-custom`) отказывается работать с ошибкой  `CSS source is not a string.`

Comment: Ну и компилируйте только его тогда. Пропишите в src путь конкретно для него, а не для всех scss. P.S. _СSS source is not a string._ - вероятно оно хочет однострочный минифицированный css. В вашем таске минификации не вижу

Comment: Так и сделаю, спасибо. А все-таки, как прописать компилирование всех подключаемых scss-файлов в единый css?

Comment: минификацию и несколько других задач я в коде не приводил, но она есть, спасибо за внимательность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сборки файлов в один можно использовать `gulp-concat`.

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

...

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(prefixer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/style'))
    .pipe(reload({
        stream: true
  }));
});
```